# JavaScript Regex Test and Replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to sanitize some chars.  I have a solution that works but I am wondering if there is a better solution that may be faster or better or if I flat out should be approaching this differently?

```
function escapeStr(_str){
    if (/\"|\'|\%/g.test(_str)) {
        _str = _str.replace(/"/g, "%22");
        _str = _str.replace(/'/g, "%27");
        _str = _str.replace(/%/g, "%25");
    }
    return _str;
}
```

And vice versa:

```
function unescapeStr(_str){
    if (/\%22|\%27|\%25/g.test(_str)) {
        _str = _str.replace(/\%22/g, '"');
        _str = _str.replace(/\%27/g, "'");
        _str = _str.replace(/\%25/g, "%");
    }
    return _str;
}
```

Comment: This would be a better suit for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: One might argue that you're going through your strings four times if one of the characters is found but otherwise that's a good solution.

Comment: This feels like just an opinion, but you can use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` for `"` and `%` in one go.  Then you can use regex to replace the `'` characters.  No need to test really.  Just run a replace and if it doesn't find it, it won't replace anything.

Comment: @abl thanks! I'll join and try it out!

Comment: @JosephMarikle thanks, I did try that encodeURIComponent but it did not get me the specific %22 since the database is collated specifically. All these chars break the query. So I specifically need to use the %chars.

Comment: @PaulPoisson `encodeURIComponent('test"test%test')` returns the string "test%22test%25test".  It should work.

Comment: [`_str = _str.replace(/["'%]/g, function($0) { return $0 === '"' ? "%22" : $0 === "'" ? "%27" : "%25"; });`](https://jsfiddle.net/mxk39unn/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew interesting solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match these chars with a single character class regex `/['"%]/g` and inside a callback replace each match with the corresponding replacement:

```js
function myQuoteStr(_str) { 
  return _str.replace(/["'%]/g, function($0) { 
    return $0 === '"' ? "%22" : $0 === "'" ? "%27" : "%25";
  });
}
console.log(myQuoteStr("\"-'-%"));

function myUnQuoteStr(_str) { 
  return _str.replace(/%2[257](?!\d)/g, function($0) { 
    return $0 === '%22' ? '"' : $0 === "%27" ? "'" : "%";
  });
}
console.log(myUnQuoteStr("%22-%27-%25"));
```

Note that, in the `myUnQuoteStr`, the `/%2[257](?!\d)/g` pattern contains a negative lookahead to make sure we do not match `%25` in `%255` string.

Comment: I like this solution because it reminded me how to use the lookahead and work with the regex return.  This is a scalable, elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you. You may also upvote the other answer to give the user credit for sharing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to use `String.prototype.replace()` function in *chain*. Also, no need to escape the `%` char:

```js
function escapeStr(_str){    
  _str = _str.replace(/%/g, "%25").replace(/"/g, "%22").replace(/'/g, "%27");
  return _str;
}

function unescapeStr(_str){
  _str = _str.replace(/%22/g, '"').replace(/%27/g, "'").replace(/%25/g, "%");
  return _str;
}

console.log(escapeStr('sdfsdf%%%""""\''));
console.log(unescapeStr('sdfsdf%25%25%25%22%22%22%22%27'));
```